# Dompdf in services not found; Controller error "Message: Class 'Dompdf' not found"

Tags: twig, microservices, slim, dompdf

I am working with symphony and slim, so I use services that can be called in my controllers, then to my twig views. I installed Dompdf with composer and added it to my list of services I my bootstrap folder. I have tried several ways to call dompdf, but still get

> Message: Class 'Dompdf' not found

## This is the code in my controller:

```
class SlipController extends \App\Controllers\Base\PageController{

function getHandler($request, $response, $args)
{

    // Instantiate Dompdf with our options
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

   // Render the HTML as PDF
   $dompdf->render();

   // Output the generated PDF to Browser (force download)
   $dompdf->stream("mypdf.pdf", [
       "Attachment" => true
   ]);
    return $this->view->render($response,'pages/slips.twig');
}
```

### In the services.php

```
<?php
$container['dompdf'] = function($container) {
    return new \Dompdf\Dompdf;
};
```

Comment: Why do you add Dompdf to your container, but create a new instance in your controller?

Comment: You don't need the container entry in this case. Try to add `use Dompdf\Dompdf;` above the controller class.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add a use statement to your code?

```php
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

class SlipController extends \App\Controllers\Base\PageController{

function getHandler($request, $response, $args)
{
...
```

Comment: This is completely orthogonal (always like using that word) to the question.

Comment: @Murat Thanks, the error "Class dompdf not found " has stopped , but it download a blank pdf page with a new error "Call to a member function build_tree() on null". please do you know why, still trying to fix it. thanks.

Comment: Yeah you don't load any HTML. Add the following:

```php
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml("ADD HTML HERE");
$dompdf->render();
```